# Google BigQuery: grant service account permissions to create jobs in only some specific datasets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, grafana, google-cloud-iam

**Problem:** I have a project in BigQuery where all my data is stored. Within this project I created multiple datasets containing different views. Now I want to use different service accounts to query the different datasets containing different views via grafana (if that matters). These users should only be able to query the views (and therefore a specific dataset) meant for them.

**What I tried:** I granted BigQuery User, Viewer or Editor permissions (I tried all of them) at a dataset level (and also BigQuery Meatadata Viewer at a project level). When I query a view, I receive the error:

`User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project xy`.

**Questions:** It is not clear to me if granting `bigquery.jobs.create` permission on project level, will allow the user to query all datasets instead of only the one I want him to access to.

Is there any way to allow the user to create jobs only on a single dataset?

Comment: I believe it is not currently possible to grant `bigquery.jobs.create` at a dataset level, this needs to be at the project level. Happy to be proven wrong here as this is something I would love too!

Comment: Do you grant only the permission (I mean with a custom role), or do you grant a pre defined role? (like `roles/bigquery.user`)

Comment: I do it with a custom role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update October 2021

I've just seen that this question did go unanswered for me back then but still gets a lot of views. I believe the possibilities changed a bit since I asked the question so here is how I'm handling it now:

- I give the respective service account the role `roles/bigquery.jobUser` on project level. This allows it to create jobs in general, however since I don't give any other permissions yet it cannot query data yet.
- Then I give the role `roles/bigquery.dataViewer` on the dataset level. That makes it possible for the service account to query **only** the dataset I granted the permission on.
- It is also possible to grant `roles/bigquery.dataViewer` on table level, what will restrict access to **only** the specific table.

In case you want the service account not only to query (view) the data, but also to insert or change it for example, replace `roles/bigquery.dataViewer` with the role having the necessary permissions (or assign that role in addition).

How to grant the permissions:

- [On dataset level](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#granting_access_to_a_dataset)
- [On table or view level](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls#create)

Comment: How can we validate that those roles are present?

Comment: @Mohith7548 Do you mean how to check if the roles were granted to a specific service account?

Comment: yes. How can we validate if `bigquery.dataViewer` role is assigned to a service account?

Comment: If you want to check who can access a specific dataset, one solution via the Console would be opening the dataset, click 'Sharing' -> 'Permissions' and then check if the service account is listed under 'BigQuery Data Viewer'. If you want to know which datasets a service account was granted access to, you could use the service account to make an API request to list all datasets (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/listing-datasets#listing_datasets_in_a_project). Only the datasets the service account has access to will be listed. However, there could be other possibilities as well.

Answer (score 0):

We had a same problem, how we solved was, created a custom role and assigned the custom role to the particular dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can grant `bigquery.user` role to a specific dataset as indicated in [this guide.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#controlling_access_to_a_dataset) The `bigquery.user` role contains the bigquery.jobs.create permission as well as other basic permissions related to querying datasets. You can check the full list of permissions for this role [in this list.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery)

As suggested above, you can also create custom roles having only the exact permissions you want by following [this piece of documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating_a_custom_role)