# 403 Access Denied: User does not have permission to query table or perhaps it does not exist

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-iam

I try to query a BigQuery table using cloud functions:
This is my python code which should work fine:

```py
data_dict = {"project_id": "propane-nomad-396712", "dataset_name": "my_data", "table_name": "db_table", "row_count": 1, "csv_size": 1, "blob_size": 0, "timestamp": "2023-08-27T19:13:52.167462"}
project_id = data_dict["project_id"]
dataset_name = data_dict["dataset_name"]
table_name = data_dict["table_name"]
row_count = data_dict["row_count"]
csv_size = data_dict["csv_size"]
blob_size = data_dict["blob_size"]
timestamp = data_dict["timestamp"]

bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id, location="europe-west3")
# also tried this: SELECT MAX(id) as last_id FROM {dataset_name}.{table_name}
query = f"""
    SELECT MAX(id) as last_id FROM {project_id}.{dataset_name}.{table_name}
"""
query_job = bq_client.query(query)
query_result = query_job.result()
for row in query_result:
    last_id = row['last_id']
```

The cloud function uses a service account which has the following roles:

```bash
roles/bigquery.user
roles/cloudfunctions.invoker
roles/pubsub.subscriber
roles/storage.admin
```

However I get the following error:

```
403 Access Denied: Table propane-nomad-396712:my_data.db_table: User does not have permission to query table propane-nomad-396712:my_data.db_table, or perhaps it does not exist in location europe-west3.
```

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520636/google-bigquery-grant-service-account-permissions-to-create-jobs-in-only-some-s) I also gave access to the dataset itself:

```sql
GRANT `roles/bigquery.user`
ON SCHEMA `propane-nomad-396712`.my_data
TO "serviceAccount:sa-func-b@propane-nomad-396712.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
```

But that did not change anything. I know the table exists in europe-west3 region and I can also query it manually in BigQuery SQL editor without issues:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `my_data.db_table`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role `role/bigquery.user` is not enough if you want to read data from a table here.

`bigquery.user` allows the creation of BigQuery Jobs but has no permission to read data from a table. I think it is missing the `bigquery.tables.getData` permission specifically.

I think you need the roles `roles/bigquery.jobUser` and `roles/bigquery.dataViewer`.

It should definetly work if you give the `roles/bigquery.admin` to your service account.

The pre-defined IAM roles for BigQuery are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions-predefined-roles).